# Что делать с рекпчами v2?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

Я делаю все по инструкциям, которые даны на антикапче, я получаю в итоге ответ, а что с ним делать дальше я понятия не имею. Никакой кнопки отправить, или чего-то подобного там нет(

Вот мой код:

```
#Ищем рукапчу на сайте
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
recaptcha_div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'recaptcha')
if len(recaptcha_div) > 0:
    recaptcha_div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('recaptcha')
    iframe = str(recaptcha_div[0].find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute('src'))
    key_captcha = iframe.replace('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=', '')
    key_captcha = key_captcha.split('&')
    key_captcha = key_captcha[0]
    print(key_captcha)
url_captcha = f'https://rucaptcha.com/in.php?key={api}&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey={key_captcha}&pageurl={url}'

#Запрашиваем решение капчи
zapros = requests.get(url_captcha).text
key_captcha = zapros.split('|')
key_captcha= key_captcha[1]
print(zapros)
time.sleep(60)

#Получем ответ капчи
url_res = f'https://rucaptcha.com/res.php?key={api}&action=get&id={key_captcha}'
answer = requests.get(url_res).text
google_captcha = answer.split('|')
google_captcha = google_captcha[1]
print(google_captcha)
```

Этот результат присылает мне анти капча
[image: это через антикапчу]
Этот результат присылает рукапча
[image: это через рукапча]

Возможно код сложно написан, можно было сделать так, как написано на рукапча api, но я там ни че не понял)

Comment: вы смогли найти решение? если да то не могли бы поделиться им

Comment: Надо вызвать Callback функцию но я блин ломаю над этим голову уже несколько дней правда на java.